# How to execute a proper comparative performance testing?

Tags: database, testing, performance

There are two compatible versions of the same Product (e.g. database engine) that I want to compare to each other for the same input scenario (SQL query).

The problems that I want to address at first is the instability and stochastic nature of the System the Product is running on:

- CPU throttling,
- random context switching,
- third-party processes running aside,
- memory allocator page faults,
- filesystem fragmentation (at least when loading the binary in memory),
- etc.

All of this stuff potentially may be ruled out by a good probabilistic model, but I don't know how to invent the good one.

Let me formulate the task:

- approximate test mean time is 500ms, which is comparable to a systematic error of the System,
- determine with probability *p1* that the new version is faster than old one,
- determine with probability *p2* that the new version is slower than old one,
- run both versions on given scenario as few times as possible.

How to build up such model? Is it possible in runtime or the parameters should be tuned in simulations? How to deal with different Systems, i.e. if I run both of versions on different machines every time? (Articles, literature or scholar links are welcome)

Also may be are there other approaches for performance testing, like full CPU cycle count, or other probabilistic approaches?

**Example.**

I want to run both of versions for no more than 7 times for each one. I have a formulae representing some Model, like

```
bool NewFaster(new_run_time1, new_run_time2, …, old_run_time1, old_run_time2, …)
```

and it's proven that the result `true` is *true* with probability 95%, and the result `false` is *true* with probability 80%.

Comment: If someone will explain the downvotes, it would be appreciated. I will have a chance to improve my question.

Answer (score 4):

In general:

- minimize variance where possible
- collect lots of data
- throw away bad data
- apply some statistics

### Minimizing variance

You have already identified some possible error sources, e.g. context switching or CPU behaviour. You can minimize these errors e.g. by:

- shutting down non-essential processes on the system (anti-virus, web browsers, background updates, …)
- running the test repeatedly so that you can apply statistics
- running the same test multiple times in a row in order to amortize setup times
- running the tests in alternating order to reduce impact of longer-term effects

### Collect lots of data

More data allows more accurate estimates. You can get useful results with as few as four data points, but even with hundreds of data points there is a good probability that you are mis-estimating the ordering. This can be the case in particular when the two tests have very close results.

### Throw away bad data

As a heuristic, it can be useful to throw away data that is likely to distort the overall distribution. For example:

- throw away the first run as “warmup”
- throw away the best and worst results for each case (aka trimming the tails)
- throw away outliers using some more complex mechanism, e.g. using Tukey fences

### Apply statistics

There are two ways to run this kind of benchmark test: live/online, and offline. Live tuning is suitable when you can run both configurations in production, and want to minimize costs even before knowing very well which variant is better. There is lots of material on A/B tests that apply here. In particular, Bayesian methods such as Thompson sampling are relevant because they are provably optimal or almost optimal, meaning they need the fewest samples.

For offline tests, we first select a suitable number of trials and then run some statistics on the results. You can estimate the number of trials needed to achieve sufficient statistical power, but YOLO so pick some number between 20–200.

Depending on what answers we want from the data, we have to apply a suitable statistical test. As a basic question, we might be interested in finding out which test is faster. The null hypothesis would be that both tests are equally fast. We can then apply the Mann–Whitney test, which is fairly robust because it only looks at the ranks of results (not the specific values) and doesn't require the values to be normally distributed. The statistical test produces an *effect size* which indicates which configuration, if any, is typically faster, and a *p-value* which indicate the confidence in this result – smaller p-values mean that an error is less likely (but the exact interpretation of that value is tricky).

The calculations can be done fairly easy in Python:

```py
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu

def test_is_faster(x, y):
  result = mannwhitneyu(x, y, alternative='two-sided')
  # rank-biserial correlation:
  #  -1: x is always higher
  # < 0: x is usually higher
  # = 0: both are roughly equal
  # > 0: y is usually higher
  #  +1: y is always higher
  correlation = 1 - (2 * result.statistic) / (len(x) * len(y))
  return result.pvalue, correlation
```

I have prepared three data sets `x, y, z` with 20 entries each, assuming that the values are some indicator of speed (higher is better). We can compare the first two:

```py
>>> test_is_faster(x, y)
(0.8604309737352772, 0.03500000000000003)
```

The p-value 0.86 is not really significant (significance levels are often chosen at around p < 0.05). The effect size points towards y being *slightly* faster, but this is not significant. Much more tests would be needed to get a significant result! Therefore: we should stick with the null hypothesis that the two configurations are equally fast.

Let's compare x and z instead:

```py
>>> test_is_faster(x, z)
(0.0006219975867469958, 0.635)
```

Now, the effect size/correlation 0.635 shows that z is *usually* faster, and the p-value < 0.001 indicates that this result is very significant. However, some of the x runs were faster than some z runs.